# Getting dynamic variable in next for loop python

Tags: python, loops, variables, dynamic, rinside

How can I get c variable value inside the for x in range?
Code

```
str1=1
str2=100
n=int(input('vvedite kolichestvo: '))#4
r=7
while str1<str2:
  str1=str1+1
  for i in range(n):#4
    i=i+1#3
    globals()['summ{}'.format(r+i)] = r+i
    c=globals()['summ{}'.format(r+i)]
    print(c)
        for x in range(1, c+1):
           print(f"6 and {((x-1)%10)+1} and {(x - 1) // 10} and {x}")
```

If c=8, then inside the `for x in range (1, n):`
`print(f"6 and {((x-1)%10)+1} and {(x - 1) // 10} and {c}")`

Comment: **NEVER** assign anything in`globals`, actually just forget that it exists. Using `globals` will create more problems than you expect to solve ;) just use `c=r+i`

Comment: can you clarify the question

Comment: If you need a list, then use a list.  If you need to look up by name, use a dictionary.  Use the right tools for the job.

Comment: *don't use dynamic variable to begin with*